# Как наложить изображение на карту Yandex.Maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api, yandex-maps-api, карты

Доброе время суток всем. Возникла потребность наложить изображение в определенное место на карте с использованием Yandex.Maps. Похожее я нашел в Google, [вот тут](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/groundoverlay-simple?hl=ru).
Кто то может знает, как такое самое сделать с помощью Yandex? Заранее спасибо)

Comment: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/Layer-docpage/

Answer (score 1):

Есть 2 основных способа:

1. Создать собственный [тайловый слой](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/Layer-docpage/?from=SO) карты, подробнее описано [в статье документации](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/dg/concepts/hotspots/image-layer-docpage/?from=SO) - изображение потребуется нарезать на тайлы, которые будут отображаться поверх соответствующих тайлов карты; также потребуется подготовить нарезанное изображение для разных уровней зума.
2. Создать многоугольник нужной формы и использовать изображение в качестве заливки, как [показано в примере](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/polygon_with_image?from=SO), с помощью опций:

   ```
   fillImageHref: 'images/lake.png',
   fillMethod: 'stretch'
   ```